# How to create a list of element-wise pairs from two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

As an example, given

```
A = {a, b, c}
B = {x, y, z}
```

How do I create?

```
C = {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}
```

Comment: `C=Table[{A[[i]], B[[i]]}, {i, 1, 3}]={{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}`

Comment: @SachinKumar  Thank you.

Comment: `Transpose[{A,B}]` or `Thread[{A, B}]`

Comment: `Transpose[{A, B}]`

Comment: @all [finding duplicates / there is a function for that / Transpose](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2404/5478)

Comment: @kuba I did not ask for a table of data.  the question itself is very different than this.  I spent a lot of time searching for this answer and didn't find it.  My question is very specific and easy to find. And Table is not the only way to solve this, in fact table is more awkward.  The upshot is, I believe this question will be useful to people and make it easier to find this solution.  It's utility is reason to not delete it.

Comment: @RFS where did I say Table? The accepted answer in the linked topic uses `Transpose`, which is the way to go in your case, or did I miss something? p.s. questions marked as duplicate won't be deleted but stay as road signs.

Comment: @kuba Ok, I was just concerned about deletion.  Regarding table:  You're right the method "How to make a table from two lists?" uses Transpose.  Thanks for your guidance to someone fairly new to the platform.

Answer (score 4):

SUMMARIZING ALL THE METHODS GIVEN IN THE COMMENTS

Given two lists

```
A = {a, b, c}
B = {x, y, z}
```

Each of the following

```
Transpose[{A, B}]

Thread[{A, B}]

MapThread[List, {A, B}]

Table[{A[[i]], B[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[A]}]
```

yield

```
{{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, z}}
```